# Biblatex \citeauthor style

Tags: biblatex

I am using BibLatex with the configuration below:

```
\usepackage[backend = biber,  
        language = english ,
        style    = alphabetic ,  
        firstinits = true,
        isbn = false,
        url = false,
        doi = false,
        sorting = nyt,
        backref=true
        ]{biblatex}
```

Is it possible to change the current \citeauthor 'lastname style' (e.g. "Doe") by an 'abbreviated-firstname lastmane' style (e.g. "J. Doe")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `\citeauthor` uses the `labelname` format. With your set-up you could simply use

```
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}
```

That works well since you don't use the `labelname` format in citations (your style is `alphabetic`) and you already have `giveninits=true` (`giveninits` was called `firstinits` in older versions) so we only ever get initials.

With other styles that use `labelname` you might need

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames[given-family]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

instead.

If you don't have `giveninits=true` enabled, use

```
\DeclareNameFormat{g-family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames[g-family]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion outputs "DoeD.JohnJ." instead of "J. Doe". Moreover, it does not separate multiple authors. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It works just fine for me. Maybe you are using an older version of `biblatex`, the code will only work with versions >= 3.3. If you can't update, try `\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}` instead.

Comment: @suitangi ^^^^^

Comment: Works great after updating. Thank you very much!

Comment: The first simple approach `\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}` works well with `ieee` style as well, thanks for your explanation!